# How to match parentheses and comma formatting in list, python

Tags: python, list, formatting, parentheses

I am trying to combine entries from two columns in a spreadsheet into a single list in python. The first column contains the first person in every pair and is the person who asked the question, the questioner. The second is the person who responded: the answerer. I want the list to look like this:

```
[('Jack', 'Jill'), ('Jack', 'John'), ('Jack', 'Jason'), ('Jill', 'John')...]
```

However, my list looks like this:

```
['(Jack, Jill)', '(Jack, John)', '(Jack, Jason)', '(Jack, john)'...]
```

The key difference is that in the first list, the quotation marks are on the inside of the parentheses and in the second, they are on the outside.

Here's my process:

```
answerers = line['answerers'].split(" ")
for answerer in answerers:
    edgelist.append("(" + line['questioner'] + ", " + answerer + ")")
```

What should I do differently to have the quotation marks on the inside, around each person, rather than on the outside?

Comment: how is `line` defined?

Comment: I'm sorry: line is the iterator for a large nested for loop which goes through the whole spreadsheet. So a line is a row in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @goldisfine you can posts few lines then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just keep them as two seperate lists, for example `asker` and `answerer` then do this

```
>>> asker = ['Jack','Jack','Jack','Jill']
>>> answerer = ['Jill','John','Jason','John']
>>> finalList = zip(asker, answerer)
>>>
>>>
>>> finalList
[('Jack', 'Jill'), ('Jack', 'John'), ('Jack', 'Jason'), ('Jill', 'John')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
edgelist.append((  line['questioner'] ,answerer))
```

assuming I understand your question

Comment: Thanks Joran, that answered the question!

Answer (score 0):

Or in a single line:

```
edgelist = [(line['answerer'], answerer) for answerer in answerers]
```